# Calling number from PhoneGap application

Tags: cordova

I'm beginner with PhoneGap. I previously used CoronaSdk and APPInventor for my mobile apps. I'd like PhoneGap. I'm building an mobile app that calls an number, but I don't know how to do so?

I need some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tel: URI. It will invoke the native dialer app with the specified number.

This applies to all PhoneGap platforms.

```
<a href="tel:18008888888">Bob Smith</a>
```

Comment: Hi this method it works but the cann don't start automatic. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a way to automatically call a number (in IOS at least). Remember phonegap is a web view with access to native features. You would still require direct user interaction to call a number.

Comment: You can actually send the user to the dialer by using the URI: tel:number. You can do it using window.location()

Comment: Its still prompts you with an alert saying 'Call: 0123456778'. Its not automatic.